# add a web service reference to a console app

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wcf, web-services, console

Im creating a simple web service in a console app. (PersonService)
this is my Program.cs below

im trying to add a service reference to a different console app (PersonClient)
how can i do this?
i tried adding it by right clicking, add service reference, pointing to the refernce etc...
but it wont work.

```
        [DataContract]
        public class Person
        {
            [DataMember]
            public string FirstName { get; set; }

            [DataMember]
            public string LastName { get; set; }

        }

        [ServiceContract]
        public interface IPersonLookup
        {
            [OperationContract]
            Person GetPerson(int identifier);
        }

        public class PersonService : IPersonLookup
        {
            public PersonService()
            {
            }
            public Person GetPerson(int identifier)
            {
                Person p = new Person();
                p.FirstName="Jane";
                p.LastName="Doe";
                return p;
            }



        }


        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(PersonService)))
                {
                    WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding();
                    host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IPersonLookup), binding, "http://localhost:9090/PersonService");
                    host.Open();
                    Console.WriteLine("Listening....");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }


            }
        }
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Solution:**

1. Create a console application using visual studio.
2. Right click on the project and click on "Add Service Reference...".
3. On the window, you will find the "Advanced" button at the bottom.
4. Click on the button and it will open service reference settings window. It has a button at bottom called "Add Web Reference".

Comment: As given link in actual answer is not working anymore but I tried this and it is working fine for me. Thanks!! @raklos mark this solution as answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read about WCF MEX Endpoints. Here's a [blog post that may help](http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/dennis/archive/2006/11/09/WCF-Part-4-_3A00_-Make-your-service-visible-through-metadata.aspx).

Comment: Link is not working anymore. Please update your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have two console exes, one which runs a `ServiceHost` - is that correct? Run the server console without debugging; then in the IDE add the WCF reference to the url. It should work, but it needs the server (your second console exe) to be running when you query the mex.

Comment: Hi Marc,
I did what you said and

i pointed address to: http://localhost:9090/PersonService

 and it gives this error:
There was an error downloading 'http://localhost:9090/PersonService'.
The request failed with HTTP status 400: Bad Request.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://localhost:9090/PersonService'.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://localhost:9090/PersonService'.
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.

Comment: When it is running, try browsing to the service uri in your web-browser. It may give you the service page that tells you how to set up mex; I can't remember off the top of my head, though.

Comment: when i point to http://localhost:9090/PersonService whilst the service is running it gives a page not found.

Answer (score 0):

When you added the webservice reference, you defined the namespace and 'class name' for the service.  You must either add the namespace reference ("using FooNameSpace;") or use the fully qualified class name of the service ("FooNameSpace.BarClass ws = new FooNameSapce.BarClass()");

Answer (score 0):

No one mentioned yet that you need a couple things before you can use "Add Service Reference".

1. Use the Visual Studio 2019 Installer tool to modify your existing installation.
2. Check the ".NET Desktop Development Workload". (This will add a second type of console app.)
3. Now launch VS 2019 and then create a project using: Console App (.NET Framework) IMPORTANT: Do not select the one for .NET Core, or it will not have the "Add Service Reference" option!
4. Now go to the main menu bar and select Project -> Add Service Reference. Now you can add your reference.

Happy coding!

Answer (score -1):

- Create a console application.
- Right click on the References and click on Add Service
  Reference.
- Click on Advanced button at the bottom.
- In the New Window click on Add Web Reference.

  [image]

[image]